# Vue - Loosing child reactivity by passing props from parent, dependent on the state

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, state, vuex

In my code I'm deleting an 'exercise' object successfully from the state, but it is not getting deleted on the component. The parent component takes in the data from the state and passes the 'exercises' array to the child where it can be deleted.

```
Index passes the exercises as selectedRoutine to RoutinePanel

<v-row v-else justify="center">
  <v-col cols="12" sm="9" md="7" class="text-center">
    <RoutinePanel
      :selected-day="selectedDay"
      :selected-routine="selectedRoutine"
    />
  </v-col>
</v-row>

Then RoutinePanel passe each exercise as a prop to HorizontalExercises

<div v-for="exercise in selectedRoutine" :key="exercise.name">
  <HorizontalExercises :exercise="exercise" :selected-day="selectedDay" />
</div>

HorizontalExercises

export default {
  props: {
    exercise: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => {
        return {
          name: 'Exercise',
          sets: 0,
          reps: 0,
          weight: 0,
          id: 0,
        }
      },
    },
    selectedDay: {
      type: String,
      default: () => {
        return ''
      },
    },
  },
```

Inside HorizontalExercises I have a function that successfully deletes the exercise from state, but I can't get it to dissapear from the component prop so it doesn't renders. It only dissapears when I re-render the RoutinePanel component.

The state looks something like this:

```
  routines: [
    {
      day: 'monday',
      exercises: [
        {
          name: 'bicycle',
          duration: '5 min',
          id: 0,
        },
    ]
```

Here`s the mutation used:

```
deleteExercise(state, payload) {
  const routineIndex = state.routines.findIndex(
    (routine) => routine.day === payload.day
  )
  const exerciseIndex = state.routines[routineIndex].exercises.findIndex(
    (exercise) => exercise.id === payload.id
  )
  state.routines[routineIndex].exercises.splice(exerciseIndex, 1)
},
```

i'm thinking on just making everything dependant from the state and not passing props may work.

Sorry maybe a bit confusing it`s my first question.

Comment: Which function did you used when deleting the object ?

Comment: Hi Gonzalo, I think that the best way to accomplish what you are trying is to $emit an event from the child which you can then run a method on the parent to update the state, and then the reactivity should work fine, but without the full code I couldn't answer it properly.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you are trying to pass values from the state
`:selected-routine="selectedRoutine"` if your variable is passed from `this.$store.state.selectedRoutines` it might not work (it was not reactive for me).

If so then try using the `getters` instead.
https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html

You can map them in your data and pass them down as props, it's reactive in my project. And then you can map your getters in your `computed` properties. https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#the-mapgetters-helper

Comment: I was using getters and then passing it as a prop, but didn`t work. I managed to do it by making a copy of the getter in the component and modifying that one instead of the store, and now it is reactive, then i modify the store. Thanks.